# Rename file in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, redhat

I'm having a weird Error when i try to run a simple script on docker container on redhat machine, this is the Docker file

```
From tomcat:7.0.70-jre7
ENV CLIENTNAME geocontact
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ADD app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY app.sh /
```

ENTRYPOINT ["/app.sh"]

and app.sh is the script that cause the problem "only on redhat"

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/client1.war
catalina.sh run
```

and the error message :

> mv cannot move '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war to a subdirectory of itself, '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/client1.war'

[a screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po9QX.png) 
and this only on redhat, i run the same image on ubuntu and centos with no problems.

Comment: It's strongly preferable that you copy-and-paste error messages into your post, rather than re-typing them.  Otherwise it makes it hard to be confident that we're looking at the real problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i put a screenshot for the output i hope this will help

Comment: Can you show `ls -al /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` ?

Comment: @AstraSerg the thing is that the container crash because of this error so i can not attache the container to run commands

Comment: @Amine just add this command in the app.sh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can split your command in 2 commands :

```
cp /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/client1.war
rm /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```

Answer (score 19):

In your Dockerfile: `ADD fileA fileB`. That will rename `fileA` to `fileB` at the moment of image creation.

Answer (score -3):

you can edit file inside container and commit changes without buiding image.

**docker commit existing_containername commited_image_name**

then run container with new for example

**docker run --name tomcat -td commited_image_name**